# MS Word VBA: How to Execute a Code from a Specific Line in a Word Document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to modify the following code so it executes from a specific line in my word document instead of executing from the beginning.

```
Dim formula As OMath

For Each formula In ActiveDocument.OMaths
    formula.Range.Font.TextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next
```

For example, I have a document with 1000 lines. Some of the lines have equations (`OMath` type). I want to run the code to change the color of equations starting from line 600 to end of the document.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it acceptable that you select the starting point? Or can you work with paragraphs instead of "lines"? (Unsure what you mean by "line"...) The reason is that a "line" is not an object in Word; a selection or a paragraph are. So it's reasonably quick and easy to specify either of these as a starting point...

Comment: Hey, my math document is broken down into chapters. What I need is to, let say, starting from chapter 3, all the equation from there on to be red color. @Mikku suggestion is actually nice except I have to select all the paragraphs. Can his solution be modified to run from a certain page?

Comment: Carlo, are the starting points (chapters, for example) something formatted with a specific style? Would it be an acceptable approach, for example, for the macro to show an "input" where you type a search term and then that term and the style can be searched? Or if you could use Word's built-in navigation pane to select the starting point? I'm trying to find a simple and fast way that doesn't involve a lot of coding...

Comment: Hey, to answer your questions: 1?) the entire document style is `Normal` 2?) I am willing to change the style, if necessary, and make the idea work 3?) not sure what that is..

Comment: In excel, you can specify something like: `row = 600` and `Range("A" & row).value = ...` then `row = row + 1`. This will execute the code from cell 600 and up. I was hoping something like this exist in word..

Comment: Only with paragraphs, not with lines. Word is different :-) You have to learn to think a bit differently. A page number?

Comment: Page number would work too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

```
Sub FormatOMaths()

    Dim cursorPosition As Long
    Dim formula As OMath

    cursorPosition = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\startOfSel").Start

    For Each formula In ActiveDocument.Range(cursorPosition, ActiveDocument.Content.End).OMaths
        formula.Range.Font.TextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

With this code, you click from where you want to execute the code and goes all  the way to the end of document.

Comment: My very first question to you was: "Is it acceptable that you select the starting point" and I didn't get a clear answer. Otherwise you'd have had this three days ago. There's a much simpler way: cursorPostion = Selection.Start, no need to go the long route over a bookmark...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)` property to get the line number.

[More Info Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdinformation) - *This will give you the line number on that current page.*

---

**Edit:** You may need to use the `Absolute Line Number`

**Code:**

```
Sub getline()

Dim formula As OMath

For Each formula In ActiveDocument.OMaths
    With formula.Range
        If GetAbsoluteLineNum(formula.Range) > 600 Then .Font.TextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
Next

End Sub

Function GetAbsoluteLineNum(r As Range) As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, Count As Integer, rTemp As Range

    r.Select
    Do
        i1 = Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
        Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToLine, which:=wdGoToPrevious, Count:=1, Name:=""

        Count = Count + 1
        i2 = Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
    Loop Until i1 = i2

    r.Select
    GetAbsoluteLineNum = Count
End Function
```

[Function From Here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=59)

---

**Update:** Select the Area in which you want to perform the task and run the below code

**[image: You can use this to Run it on Selected Area.]**

```
Dim formula As OMath

For Each formula In Selection.OMaths

    formula.Range.Font.TextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Next
```

Comment: Hmmm.. It doesn't accomplish the task I am looking for... It takes long time to exectue. I would like, if possible, to click on a line in the document and run the code starting from there..

Comment: @CarloSantana .. See the Update. If this still doesn't work, then you should edit the question and enter the speed and specification of the code that you require.

Comment: This actually helps! Thank you. Now, is there a way to run a code from a specific page without selecting the paragraphs? Please read my response to @Cindy Meister

Comment: @CarloSantana ... You should ask a new question now after thinking clearly about what you exactly want. Meanwhile if this answer helped, you can mark it as Accepted and Up Vote it. All the Best :)

Comment: What I want is in my original question :)

Comment: @CarloSantana And that is covered by the First Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below demonstrates how it's possible to start from within a document and perform an from a certain page number to the end of the document.

The `InputBox` gets the page number from the user (to understand what the arguments are, look at the Help topic). A `Range` object is declared and set to the entire document content, then `GoTo` puts the focus of the `Range` on the specified page. The `End` of the `Range` is then extended to the end of the document and the loop runs only on that `Range`.

```
Sub StartFromWithinDoc()
    Dim pgNum As Long
    Dim formula As OMath
    Dim rng As Word.Range

    pgNum = InputBox("On what page do you want to start?", "Update Maths", "1")
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.content
    rng.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=pgNum
    rng.End = ActiveDocument.content.End

    For Each formula In rng.OMaths 'ActiveDocument.OMaths
        formula.Range.Font.TextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Cindy, I ran your code with different numbers in the `InputBox` but it always starts from the beginning of the document.. Can you please copy/paste the above code and run it on your side?

Comment: Cindy, I figure out the solution exactly how I initially envisioned it. I posted the solution. You actually shed some light on how to approach this. Thank you for the help!